# Jenkins xcode plugin Code Signing Clarification

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, provisioning-profile

I am using the Jenkins xcode plugin to create a ".app" file to my phone (via ios-deploy).

It doesn't seem to matter whether or not I add a manual code sign to work.  In fact, I added a Bundle ID provisioning profile UUID of "otherCrap" and the application still launches fine on my device.

Is the manual provisioning file being ignored because I am deploying a ".app" to my phone?

Here's the log from the build:

`15:03:56     cd /Users/<myUser>/.jenkins/workspace/<myBuildJob>
15:03:56     export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
15:03:56

15:03:56 Signing Identity:     "iPhone Developer: <username> <password> (<someotherid>)"
15:03:56 Provisioning Profile: "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: <provision profile name>"
15:03:56                       (<some other long id>)
15:03:56 
15:03:56     /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign <some long id> --entitlements /Users/<myUser>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<jobId>/Build/Intermediates.noindex/<ios workspace>.build/Release-iphoneos/<ios workspace>.build/<ios workspace>.app.xcent --timestamp=none /Users/<myUser>/.jenkins/workspace/<build job name>/build/Release-iphoneos/<ios workspace>.app`

[image]

Comment: Having the exact same problem.. It completely ignores the manual provisioning profile and scans the entire provisioning folder choosing the first developer profile it finds that matches your Info.plist bundleId.. This has to be a bug.. It doesn't matter what you specify as the provisioning profile here under manual signing because it will ignore it. That manual signing section seems to only work for "pack ipa".. It signs once using the developer profile then generates an ipa then resigns it using the specified profile -__-.. I might switch to another CI or provider or use fastlane.

Comment: Ahh.. also discovered when using the "pack ipa".. it will only zip the very last dSYM file in the archive it creates.. That's it for me lol.. Moving on from Jenkins.. Too many bugs.